# Ethereum for Data storage of sensors

Tags: dapps

I need some help for a little Project.

The idea is that I have three Raspberry Pi devices. Each one is connected to an temperature sensor.

I want to create an autonomous system in which these objects can communicate through the Ethereum Network and send data to a fourth Raspberry.

I want do store the data Transaction in the Chain an the temperature too. So I will have the Chance to get the data in the Chain and on my Server Raspberry.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. 
You would have to have an Ethereum node running on the Raspberry PI so it can sign transactions to the blockchain whenever it detects a new reading.

Another way to make it work, but that is not completely decentralized, is having the Raspberry PIs store the data from the readings off-chain and then you could use Oraclize or another oracle service to query your off-chain db for the data from the smart contract.

Comment: Thank you! How can I put the data in the chain? I think I need a special genesis file? I think I need an extra variable for the data.